# Idle issue on a 91-92 Accord

Tags: honda, accord, idle, surging

I got this car a while ago. I started to fix it up and noticed more and more problems so I was just gonna sell it. It turns out that my truck doesn't make a good commuter. Who knew, right?

So I starting fixing up the Honda again and it has this strange idle problem. The idle surges at times and doesn't do it all the time. I replaced the spark plugs, plug wires, distributor cap, coolant temp sensor, coolant temp sender, throttle position sensor, cleaned the throttle body, and made sure my coolant levels were full. I've been reading other posts and by the sound of it it looks like I could have a problem with the fast idle thermo valve or the idle air control valve. I bought a new idle air control valve but have not put it on yet because I've read that you can adjust the fast idle thermo valve somehow, just don't know how.

Comment: At what rpm does it surge? Fast idle valve surge happens in the 1300 to 1800 range. Idle air control valves can cause problems in the under 1200 rpm range.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the idle does not need to be adjusted, especially if all it's doing is surging. Before replacing the idle air control valve, try cleaning it first. I need to do this every 2 years on a Nissan from that era when I get the same symptoms.